# How to add text in key value pair Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I had two array data which I was able to convert into a key value pair object.

```
firstArray: [] = ['a','b','c','d']
secondArray: [] = [1,2,3,4]
```

Code to convert two array to Key Value Pair:

```
let dict = firstArray.map(function(obj, index) {
let mydict = {}
mydict[secondArray[index]] = obj;
return mydict;
});

console.log(dict) 
Output: 
 [{
  "1": "a"
}, {
  "2": "b"
}, {
  "3": "c"
}, {
  "4": "d"
}]
```

Desired Output:

```
[{
 value: "1", name: "a"
}, {
value:  "2", name: "b"
}, {
value:  "3",name: "c"
}, {
 value: "4", name:"d"
}]
```

Can someone help me figure out how to achieve this.

Comment: `const result = firstArray.map((val, i) => ({ value: secondArray[i], name: val }));`

Comment: `const dict = firstArray.map((name, index) => ({value: secondArray[index], name}));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const firstArray = ['a','b','c','d'];
const secondArray = [1,2,3,4];

const dict = firstArray.map((i, index) => {
   return {
    value: secondArray[index].toString(),
    name: i
   };     
});
console.log(dict);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be possible to do so

```
let a = ['a','b','c','d'];
let b = [1,2,3,4];
let tempArray = [];
for(let i = 0;i<a.length;i++){
    
    let tempAttribute = {
        'name' : b[i],
        'value' : a[i]
    }
    tempArray.push(tempAttribute)
}
console.log(tempArray);
```

Because the subscript of the data is fixed, we can use its subscript to do something, you can also use other looping methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```js
const firstArray = ['a','b','c','d']
const secondArray = [1,2,3,4]

const result = firstArray.map((letter, index) => ({
  name: letter, 
  value: secondArray[index].toString()
}))

console.log(result)
```